# php.ini config file scan performance

Tags: php, apache

Does enabling the configuration option `with-config-file-scan-dir` when compiling PHP lead to performance issues?

Specifically, does this tell the PHP binary to do a file system scan every time the PHP module is loaded to respond to a request?

I imagine it does, and that having multiple ini files causes just a little more disk access on every request.  I suppose this could be mitigated by placing all those separate directives into the same php.ini file.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, If I understand it correctly you will provide it a directory which when the PHP config is loaded (at apache startup) PHP will read every file in the directory as a config file.

Some info [here](http://www.radwin.org/michael/blog/2006/07/phpini_hacks_withconfigfil.html) and more [here](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=122971082314313&w=2) (better link)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  I thought it loaded those conf files on each HTTP request.  Didn't realize that it loaded them when Apache was started up.

Answer (score 2):

Bryan,

The CLI/(Fast)CGI versions do load the .ini files each time they are fired up; however, the apache module loads them once into memory when the server is started. You can test this behavior by changing a value in any of the .ini files and running the CLI binary. Notice that you need a server restart before you can see the changes in the server module version.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this tell the PHP binary to do a file system scan every time the PHP module is loaded to respond to a request?

No. When you compile `--with-config-file-scan-dir=/path/to/dir` all you're doing is telling PHP combine all files in this directory into its configuration. This is a method often used in system configuration where package management systems need to be able to add/remove package specific configuration from an application without potentially destroying a  end-user modified config file. An example here would be, on a Debian based system, when you `apt-get install php-pgsql`, it will create a `/etc/php/conf.d/pgsql.ini` which will contain the `extension=pgsql.so` line, as well as any module-specific options.

> Does enabling the configuration option with-config-file-scan-dir when compiling PHP lead to performance issues?

Not really. In practice, it is simply a concatenation of all the .ini files in that particular directory.

I can tell you that Debian, CentOS, and Zend Server all use this option by default.

Also, just off the top of my head, *nix RC files, Apache2, Courier, Emacs, and Cron all use (or can use) similar approaches to loading configurations.